# Routing raw MIDI to software synth

Tags: midi, linux

I use a program that generates raw MIDI events interpreted and played by an external hardware synth connected via USB cable. This works great, but sometimes I wish to use the same program with a software synth, like Timidity++, especially when composing out of home and don't have the heavy hardware synth with me.

The problem is the program I use expects to talk to a device like hw:2,0,0 while softsynth open only MIDI port like 24:0. Can I bridge the difference and use the program with a softsynth too? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bridge from a raw MIDI port to a sequencer port, load the `snd-virmidi` module to create a virtual raw MIDI port, tell that program to use it, and connect the corresponding sequencer port to the soft synth (with `aconnect`).

If possible, your program should be changed to use the ALSA sequencer API instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I did not need to load the snd-virmidi module, but you suggested me the programmative equivalent. In my C program I use "virtual" as the device name when I call ALSA's snd_rawmidi_open to open a raw MIDI port. Then I can simply use the arecordmidi utility to get a MIDI file from this port. The only trick is to guess the port number in advance, but I think I will make my program to start and stop arecordmidi itself and generate the MIDI file without having to write additional code to support the MIDI format directly!